# Permittion Denied whilst executing '.sh'

Tags: vps

I have went and installed a piece of PHP Scripts for (mobile minecraft server software) and I went to execute the file 'start.sh' with the command;
'./start.sh'
When I pressed enter the SSH Client (Putty) it came and said 'Permittion Denied'
I have made the file permissions open with cmod. I am not sure what is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `ls -la start.sh` show?

Comment: It shows ' -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1153 Jun 22 21:44 start.sh'

Comment: What does that mean/

Answer (score 0):

The line you posted in your comment means that the owner can read and write, the owner's group can read, and everyone else can read.

Do

```
chmod +x start.sh
```

This will add the ability to execute as well as read and write.